# Uno Main Layout

Tags: uno-platform

I am new to Uno and I have been following the frame navigation [tutorial](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/guides/native-frame-nav-tutorial.html). I noticed that when the frame navigates the entire window changes. This is good but not optimal. Is there a way in Uno to have a Main Layout, like you would see in a ASP.Net MVC project? I would rather not implement the navigation menu on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not exactly what you are looking for, I believe the [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) control is your closest bet. You can disable `CompactView` and obtain something like what is showcased in [UnoGallery](http://gallery.platform.uno/).

Comment: I have been trying to use the NavigationView but I find that when the NavigationVew is expanded or collapsed it always has the same width. I don't believe this is proper functionality. Is there a property that I missed that would change the width when the NavigationView is collapsed?

Comment: What [DisplayMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.displaymode?view=winrt-20348) did you set ? 
You can also look at the `OpenPaneLength` and `CompactPaneLength` properties

Answer (score 1):

To extend on @matfillion's answer, if `NavigationView` doesn't suit your needs, you can easily roll your own navigation shell whilst leveraging the built-in frame navigation. There's no requirement for `Frame` to be the top-level control in your application.

Here's an ultra-simple example, to illustrate the principle. The navigation list will stay visible at the top whilst navigating between pages.

Shell.xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="UnoTestbed44.Shell"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="NavigationList"
                  Background="LightGray"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind Pages}"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Label"
                  SelectionChanged="NavigationList_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"
               Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Shell.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace UnoTestbed44
{
    public sealed partial class Shell : UserControl
    {
        public NavigationItem[] Pages { get; } = new[] { 
            new NavigationItem {Label = "First page", PageType = typeof(Page1)},
            new NavigationItem {Label = "Second page", PageType = typeof(Page2)},
        };
        public Shell()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NavigationList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault() is NavigationItem navigationItem)
            {
                MainFrame.Navigate(navigationItem.PageType);
            }
        }

        public class NavigationItem
        {
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public Type PageType { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Override `OnLaunched()` in App.xaml.cs:

```cs
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
#if NET5_0 && WINDOWS
            _window = new Window();
            _window.Activate();
#else
            _window = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current;
#endif

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (_window.Content == null)
            {
                _window.Content = new Shell();
            }

#if !(NET5_0 && WINDOWS)
            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
#endif
            {
                // Ensure the current window is active
                _window.Activate();
            }
        }
```